# How to user ``MembershipProvider``? - Encrypt Password

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, membership-provider

I have an external application where the Administrator can set the details of the users, so I'm looking for a way to set the password of the users.

What I need for this is the same encryption is using .NET(In the main app I have implemented all these using `WebSecurity`).

Also I saw I can duplicate the same encryption using `Membership Provider` but I can't figure out how to implement it, because `MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword` is a protected method.

Any idea how can I get the same encryption??

> Note: Example input output
>   `Password`: testtest
>
> `Encrypted password`:
>   AMIbPCqv2CKPG7xl7wAbxVvWmML1r0J1aMqTXzq5KwN56pTPp5DNdVQVUNvICRVmSQ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a way to set the password of the users

Not advisable to do so from security perspective. You should rather have a default password set on user creation and on first login force user to set a new password. This way you do not need to create a password really.

I might be overlooking your requirement but it seems you are going too far with this.